# ANDROID: get Total Sum of column from LazyList Listview (thest1/LazyList)

Tags: php, android, listview, android-listview, lazylist

I am currently developing an ordering app for our project and I'm using LazyList Listview from https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

In my listview I have a textView Price , what I want is to SUM all the textView Price in my Listview and put it to textView TotalSum

Here's the code

```
public class OrderSum extends Activity{

ListView list;
TextView id;  //// ver - id
TextView name; //// name - name
TextView quan; ////  api - desc
TextView price; ////  price
TextView order_num; ////  price
TextView cust_num; ////  price
ImageView image;

TextView items;
TextView empty;
TextView home_ornum;
TextView cust_name;

ImageButton addOrder;
ImageButton proceed;

DigitalClock time;
TextView os;

TextView o_total;


// Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    LvOrderSumAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String ID = "id";
    static String NAME = "ord_name";
    static String PRICE = "ord_price";
    static String QTY = "ord_qty";
    static String CUSTID = "customer_id";
    static String ORDER = "ord_num";
    static String PXQ = "price_x_quan";
    static String IMAGE = "image";
    static String OR = "text_ordernumber";
    static String ON = "text_name";
    static String TP = "t_price";

    private static String ordershow = "http://192.168.43.52/MMOS/api/ordershow.php";
///////////////////////

@SuppressLint({ "SimpleDateFormat", "NewApi" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_summary);

    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();

                     /**Unique ID / Customer Id***/
                     DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                     /**
                     * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
                     **/
                     HashMap user = new HashMap();
                     user = db.getUserDetails();


                     final TextView unique_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o_custnum);
                     unique_id.setText((CharSequence) user.get("uid"));

                     /**END**/

                     /** DATE VIEW***/
                     TextView h_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o_date);
                     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                      SimpleDateFormat format1;

                      format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
                     // format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");

                      h_date.setText(format1.format(c.getTime()) );
                      /** END DATE VIEW***/




     cust_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplaycustName);
     home_ornum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Displayordernum);
     time = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.o_time);


     Intent myIntent = getIntent();
     home_ornum.setText(myIntent.getStringExtra("text_ordernumber")); //order number is the TextView
     cust_name.setText(myIntent.getStringExtra("text_name")); //tv is the TextView   


     items= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayTotalItems);

     /***************Custom Font***/
     Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MavenPro.otf");
       cust_name.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
       home_ornum.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
       time.setTypeface(myCustomFont); 
       h_date.setTypeface(myCustomFont); 
     /***************Custom Font**************/  




         addOrder = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
         addOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(OrderSum.this,
                            Categories.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

                }
          });


          /***************************PROCEED BUTTON***************************/
          proceed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_proceed);
          proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(OrderSum.this,
                            OrderInformation.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    // uniq id , order no , date , name

                  //  final TextView d_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o_date);
                    Intent ord_in = new Intent ( OrderSum.this, OrderInformation.class ); 
                    ord_in.putExtra ( "text_order", home_ornum.getText().toString() );
                   // ord_in.putExtra ( "text_date", d_date.getText().toString() );
                    ord_in.putExtra ( "text_custName", cust_name.getText().toString() );
                    ord_in.putExtra ( "text_items", items.getText().toString() );
                    startActivity(ord_in);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);


                }
          });
          /***************************PROCEED BUTTON***************************/



            /**for the ROOF2**/   
                  final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
                  BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable 
                  (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roof2)); 
                  ///background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); 
                  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            /**end for the ROOF2**/


} /// end of OnCreate



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(OrderSum.this,
            Home.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);*/
    TextView on = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Displayordernum);
    Intent home_in = new Intent ( OrderSum.this, Home.class ); 
    home_in.putExtra ( "text_ordernumber", on.getText().toString() );
    startActivity(home_in); 
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

}


// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OrderSum.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Your orders");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            TextView custname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplaycustName);
            TextView homeornum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Displayordernum);

             Intent home_in = getIntent();
             homeornum.setText(home_in.getStringExtra("text_ordernumber")); //tv is the TextView  
             custname.setText(home_in.getStringExtra("text_name")); //name is the TextView



            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        JSONObject jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(ordershow) ;

            //jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(,)
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON==
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("orders");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    /* from db orders = id,ord_name,ord_desc,
                    ord_price,ord_qty,customer_id,ord_num,price_x_quan , image  jsonobjecy = from db*/
                    map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("ord_name", jsonobject.getString("ord_name"));
                    map.put("ord_price", jsonobject.getString("ord_price"));
                    map.put("ord_qty", jsonobject.getString("ord_qty"));
                    map.put("customer_id", jsonobject.getString("customer_id"));
                    map.put("ord_num", jsonobject.getString("ord_num"));
                    map.put("price_x_quan", jsonobject.getString("price_x_quan"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    map.put("text_ordernumber",home_in.getStringExtra("text_ordernumber"));
                    map.put("text_name",home_in.getStringExtra("text_name"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrderSummary);

            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new LvOrderSumAdapter(OrderSum.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.getAdapter().getCount();
            String count = ""+listview.getAdapter().getCount(); 
            items.setText(count);



            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } 
///

}
```

Here's the code for BaseAdapter , ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
// Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();



    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        TextView desc;
        TextView price;
        TextView iUrl; /// image URL
        TextView iWebUrl ; //imgage kay chels
        ImageView image;



        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_v, parent, false);
        //View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_menu, parent, false);


        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);



        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        iUrl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageUrl);
        iWebUrl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgUrlWeb);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        id.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.ID));
        name.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.NAME));
        price.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.PRICE));
        desc.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.DESCRIPTION));

        iUrl.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.IMAGE));
        iWebUrl.setText(resultp.get(C_Pastries.IMGIMG));
        //ordnum.setText(resultp.get(Products.EX));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(C_Pastries.IMAGE), image);




        // Capture ListView item click
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {
                // Get the position


                resultp = data.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Menu_Clicked.class);

                // Pass all data rank
                //String listValue = (String) data.get(position).get(Products.aa);
                intent.putExtra("id", resultp.get(C_Pastries.ID));

                intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(C_Pastries.NAME));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("description", resultp.get(C_Pastries.DESCRIPTION));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("price",resultp.get(C_Pastries.PRICE));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("image", resultp.get(C_Pastries.IMAGE));
                intent.putExtra("imgimg", resultp.get(C_Pastries.IMGIMG));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                intent.putExtra("text_ordernumber",resultp.get(C_Pastries.EX));

                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Here's the php code ordershow.php

```
    <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die ('No Connection');
mysql_select_db('dbmoms');



$sql ="SELECT * FROM orders";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr['orders'][]= $row;

}
$json = json_encode($arr);

$json_encoded_string = json_encode($arr); 
 $json_encoded_string = str_replace("\\/", '/', $json_encoded_string);

echo $json_encoded_string;

?>
```

Comment: What problem have you run into?

Comment: theres no problem in the code above , but im trying different codes on how calculate the TOTAL SUM of textView Price in my LazyList ListView but none of them works for me. Im hoping that by posting codes here will somehow give you idea on how i want to do in my project :)

Comment: Huge code dumps like that are not helpful. Consider reducing the posted code to the minimum required to highlight what you're trying to do, and skip all the fluff.